# Pagestyle, \sectionmarkformat and KOMA \DeclareSectionCommand

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, koma-script

I need own section and chapter macros with own `\sectionmarkformat`.
I try create it with: KOMA (v.3.24) `\DeclareSectionCommand`.
My MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft=false,version=last,paper=a6,twoside,open=right,headings=optiontoheadandtoc,chapterprefix=no]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareSectionCommand[%
    style=section,%
    indent=0pt,%
    level=1,%
    counterwithin=chapter,
    beforeskip=-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,%
    afterskip=2.3ex plus.2ex,%
    %   pagestyle=scrheadings,% not working for sectioin; 
    %   in log-file: auto-selection of `pagestyleset=KOMA-Script' 
    toclevel = 1,
    tocindent=1.5em,% 
    tocnumwidth=2.3em,%
    font=\usekomafont{section}%
]{zsection}

\DeclareSectionCommand[%
    style=chapter,%
    level=0,%
    beforeskip=-3\baselineskip,%
    afterskip=1.5\baselineskip plus .1\baselineskip minus .167\baselineskip,%
    pagestyle=scrheadings,
    toclevel = 0,
    tocindent=0pt,% 
    tocnumwidth=1.5em,%
    font=\usekomafont{chapter}%
]{zchapter}

%\renewcommand*{\zsectionmarkformat}{\thezsection\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand*{\zsectionmarkformat}{}

\begin{document}

\zchapter[tocentry={Zchapter},head={zchap}]{Zhapter Title text}
    \zsection[tocentry={Zsection},head={zsec}]{Zsection Title text}
    \lipsum
\chapter[tocentry={Chapter},head={chap}]{Chapter title text}
    \section[tocentry={Section},head={sec}]{Section title text}
    \lipsum
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

In text and TOC all printed normally (almost). But I have **no** *running headers* for new `\zsection` and `\zchapter`, contrary to usual sections.

Perhaps `pagestyle` not using here?
Can I apply `pagestyle` for new section? Or I need some other way (`patchcmd`, `renewcommand{\section}` etc.)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
\automark*[zsection]{zchapter}
```

to get running headers for the new section commands, too.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a6,
  headings=optiontoheadandtoc,
  ]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[headsepline,
  automark% <- added
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareSectionCommand[%
    style=section,%
    indent=0pt,%
    level=1,%
    counterwithin=chapter,
    beforeskip=-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,%
    afterskip=2.3ex plus.2ex,%
    toclevel = 1,
    tocindent=1.5em,% 
    tocnumwidth=2.3em,%
    font=\usekomafont{section}%
]{zsection}

\DeclareSectionCommand[%
    style=chapter,%
    level=0,%
    beforeskip=-3\baselineskip,%
    afterskip=1.5\baselineskip plus .1\baselineskip minus .167\baselineskip,%
    %pagestyle=scrheadings,% I would suggest to use plain as for normal chapters
    toclevel = 0,
    tocindent=0pt,% 
    tocnumwidth=1.5em,%
    font=\usekomafont{chapter}%
]{zchapter}

\automark*[zsection]{zchapter}% <- added
\renewcommand*{\zsectionmarkformat}{}% there will be unnumbered zsections in header

\begin{document}

\zchapter[tocentry={Zchapter},head={zchap}]{Zhapter Title text}
    \zsection[tocentry={Zsection},head={zsec}]{Zsection Title text}
    \lipsum
\chapter[tocentry={Chapter},head={chap}]{Chapter title text}
    \section[tocentry={Section},head={sec}]{Section title text}
    \lipsum
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

---

If you use **KOMA-Script version 3.24 or newer** and `beforeskip` and `afterskip` for the new `zchapter` should be the same as for `chapter`, you can remove this two options from `\DeclareSectionCommand`. Starting with version 3.24 the values of `beforeskip` and `afterskip` from `chapter` and `part` will be used for new sectioning commands using `style=chapter` and `style=part` respectively.

With some additional changes:

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a6,
  headings=optiontoheadandtoc,
  %headings=normal% default is big
  ]{scrbook}[2017/09/07]% code needs version 3.24 or newer
\usepackage[headsepline,
  automark% <- added, does the same as \automark[section]{chapter}
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[% <- ...New... to ensure its really new
    style=chapter,%
    level=\chapternumdepth,% <- changed: use the same level as chapter
    toclevel=\chaptertocdepth,% <- changed: use the same level as chapter
    tocindent=0pt,% 
    tocnumwidth=1.5em,%
    tocentryformat={\usekomafont{chapterentry}},% <- added to use the same font settings in ToC
    tocpagenumberformat={\usekomafont{chapterentry}\usekomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}},% <- added
    toclinefill=\hfill% <-added
]{zchapter}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[% <- ...New... to ensure its really new
    style=section,%
    level=\sectionnumdepth,% <- changed: use the same level as section
    counterwithin=chapter,
    beforeskip=-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,%
    afterskip=2.3ex plus.2ex,%
    toclevel = \sectiontocdepth,% <- changed: use the same level as section
    tocindent=1.5em,% 
    tocnumwidth=2.3em,%
    font=\usekomafont{section}%
]{zsection}

\automark*[zsection]{zchapter}%<- added
\renewcommand*{\zsectionmarkformat}{}% there will be unnumbered zsections in header

\begin{document}

\zchapter[tocentry={Zchapter},head={zchap}]{Zhapter Title text}
    \zsection[tocentry={Zsection},head={zsec}]{Zsection Title text}
    \lipsum
\chapter[tocentry={Chapter},head={chap}]{Chapter title text}
    \section[tocentry={Section},head={sec}]{Section title text}
    \lipsum
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's work fine. One little subquestion, if possible. If i try set default value (from documentation) for `beforeskip=-3\baselineskip-\parskip` for chapter, this is not compiled: ``! Package scrbase Error: unknown option `beforeskip=3\baselineskip -\parskip '.`` (In my MWE I delete `-\parskip` for compiling). Is there some ideas?

Comment: Use `beforeskip=\dimexpr 3\baselineskip-\parskip\relax`. But note this is the default value for `headings=normal` and `scrbook` uses `headings=big` by default. So you will get different skips for `chapter` and `zchapter`.

Comment: Do you really want `numberwithin=chapter` for `zsection`?

Comment: Thank you. In my book I have some `chapters` with only one `section`. And for this "zero" section I need alternative `markformat` (numbering in r-header, etc). But hierarhically this z-secion exist into usual `chapter`. In a similar, there is `part` with only one, "zero"-`chapter`.  
As for \dimexpr - this not compiled too unfortunatelly.  
And yes, I mistook about default "big" headings, thank you again!

Comment: @Evgeny Maybe you can accept the answer if it solves your issue.